# How to Remove Duplicate entries from an array in Android

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Remove Duplicates from an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056729/java-remove-duplicates-from-an-array)

```
String={3333,4444,5555,5555,1111}
```

Using Delimiter i have put the String values in an `array[]..`

Now, How can i remove the same entries in an Array???

Comment: when you posted any question, 1st search answer is already available or not.

Comment: Ya..thanks..but am getting string elements dynamically..so when i use an array it should be automatically removed..post here if u know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Set` instead, Or use temporarily `Set` and get the unique result back to array

**See**

- [What interface in Java can I use to store unique objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203917/what-interface-in-java-can-i-use-to-store-unique-objects)